# surface area using cylindrical coordinates

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, surfaces, plane-curves, cylindrical-coordinates

I'm going a little crazy to be able to figure this out. I have the surface given by the $z = xy$ plane inside the cylinder $x^2+ y^2=1$.
When I do the integral by Cartesian coordinates and then converting to polar.

$$
A = \int\int\sqrt{1 + (\partial z/\partial x)^2 + (\partial z/\partial y )^2}\,dx \, dy .
$$
**EDIT:**
$$
A = \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\sqrt{1 +  \rho  ^2}\,\rho d\rho d\theta .
$$
$$
A =  \frac{2\pi}{3}(2 \sqrt{2} - 1).
$$
When I try to solve it by cylindrical coordinates I do not get the same result. How could i get it using cylindrical coordinates
?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\quad dxdy=\rho d\rho d\theta$.